# How to synchronize a program on a website live for all viewers?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React program/game that I need to run at the same time for every person viewing. Every time I load it locally, it produces a different output and I basically need it to be run server side one singular time, but I have no idea where to start. I've tried googling stuff but I'm not wordsmithing my searches correctly because I can't find anything relevant. Anything helps, thank you! (If this doesn't make sense, picture a "premier" of something special, where it happens at a set time for everybody)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for some real-time feature, do you know about socket.io

Comment: Yes a real-time feature is pretty much exactly what I need. I will look into it some, what is it exactly?